# What is the difference between "をいかがですか" and "はいかがですか"?

Tags: word-choice

I saw both are in use. What's the different here?

Based on knownledge from primary textbooks, "は" seems better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

～をいかがですか is occasionally used, but it is much less common (only one hit on BCCWJ as compared to >500 hits of はいかがですか), and some people may say it's unnatural or incorrect. I don't see any semantic difference.

Note that they are interchangeable only when it means "how about (having) ～" (e.g., コーヒーを/はいかがですか). You cannot use を when it means "how is ～ like" (e.g., 体調はいかがですか) or "why don't you ～" (e.g., 訪問されてはいかがですか).

Comment: Could it be that the variant using を is implying a verb for the object while also shortening the phrase in its implication? The は variant is very "catch-all" and probably "more" correct in the sense of "As for X, how about it?" as opposed to, say, in the case of coffee "How about some coffee (to drink)?" where the part in parentheses is implied as if the sentence were コーヒーを（飲めば）いかがですか。

Comment: I'm also wondering whether 'を' implies a verb (e.g. having) after it whilst omitted, as 'は' looks more formal in grammar.